# Keep context when passing a function from a component to a Service class

Tags: angular, typescript, delegates

I'm trying to create a `KeyboardShortcutService` that offers a `registerShortcut` function that registers a keyboard combination and its handler.

```
public registerShortcut(keyCombination:string, handler : (event) => any) : void {
    this.renderer.listen(document, `keydown.${keycombination}`, handler)
  }
```

Imagine one of my components using this service like so:

```
   shortCutService.registerShortcut('control.shift.p', this.printPage);

   public printPage()
   {
       var urlToPrint = this.someVariableInThisObject;
       //other stuff, not important
   }
```

So if a user would press CTRL+SHIFT+P, the `printPage` function will be executed.

But this gives me the error that 'this' is undefined. It seems clear to me that my `printPage` function is not being executed in the context of the original component.

How do I fix my syntax to preserve this context?

Comment: Fair point, I have edited the title to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
shortCutService.registerShortcut(
 'control.shift.p', 
  () => this.printPage()
)
```

Arrow functions get the `this` context of the execution context in which they're initialized

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it out thanks to you. For any in the future reading this, it is also mighty important that you don't forget the brackets after `this.printPage` as I did. So write `() => this.printPage()` instead of `() => this.printPage`